# Models and versions not accessible through Method: projects.models.list

Tags: google-cloud-ml

In this link
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.models/list, there is a "try this API" section.
I have given my project details and clicked on execute, it is not returning the versions or models in my project. it is only giving 200 as the response. I have given ML Engine Admin and ML engine developer as the roles to the IAM. what additional configuration should we do?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with the permissions, because if it was it wouldn't return 200 (HTTP is OK). Moreover, the roles that you have assigned havethe sufficient permissions to use that service, which is ml.models.list.

I have tested the [Try this API](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.models/list) section and it also gave me the 200 response without any model(s) on the response body. I went ahead and called the API directly and it succeeded on giving me the models and versions. You can use the following command:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<YOUR-PROJECT>/models
```

It seems to be something with the call that the Try this API section is doing, however the API seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It may not have anything to do with your question,

I use "Vertex AI", not "AI Platform".
I was able to get a list of models below.

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/locations/us-central1/models
```

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.models/list

(I thought you wouldn't get it back with code 200 if it was a permission issue.)